# Trouble assigning value in GO

Tags: pointers, go, data-structures

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting the error: `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Let's say I have this code (this is not the real one but similar):

```
type (

    Cat struct {
        Name string 
    }

    Dog struct {
        Name string 
    }

    Pets struct{
        c *Cat
        d *Dog
    }
)

func (c *Cat) Rename(d Dog) string {
     err := SomeErrorChecks()
     name := strings.TrimSpace(d.Name)
     c.Name = name // In this line is where I get the error

     return err         
}

func (p *Pets) SomeFunction() string{
    p.d = &Dog{} 
    p.c = &Cat{}

    p.d.Name = " Foo "

    err := p.c.Rename(*p.d)

    return err
}

func main(){
    //some code

    err := SomeFunction()

    //some error handling not relevant
}
```

I've checked that `strings.TrimSpace(d.Name)` returns de desired string. And I've checked that the type of `c.Name` is string. So, why I can't assing `name` to `c.Name` if both are the same type?

Comment: Show the actual code you're using. You are calling `Rename` with a nil receiver, but it's now shown here.

Comment: @JimB I can't show the actual code. I tried to reproduce it as best as possible editing the code shown before. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JimB is right, if the error is coming from where you're saying it is, then `c` is `nil`. Instead of checking the type of `c.Name` you should check that `c` is not `nil` inside the `Rename` method.

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres here's an example https://play.golang.org/p/5YiDL3ucc6

Comment: @mkopriva din-din We have a winner. First day programing on go. Write an answer and I will accept it. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JimB already pointed out in his comment

> You are calling `Rename` with a nil receiver

which means that, since you're getting the error at `c.Name = name`, the `c` receiver inside the `Rename` method is `nil`. You need to make sure to initialize `c` before calling `Rename`.

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/5YiDL3ucc6)

Comment: Thanks for clarify @JimB answer.

Comment: The problem with the nil receiver doesn't ocurr in my example with the assignation `p := &Pets{}`

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with the code.  Maybe just the code style and the method name.  To make it work I added some return values that you should adjust and removed the C++ style comments.

Note that the problem with a nil receiver is not an issue because of the `p := &Pets{}` assignment.

https://play.golang.org/p/bavuUn9IpT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type (

    Cat struct {
        Name string 
    }

    Dog struct {
        Name string 
    }

    Pets struct{
        c *Cat
        d *Dog
    }
)

func (c *Cat) Rename(d Dog) (string, error) {
     name := strings.TrimSpace(d.Name)
     c.Name = name
     return "", nil
}

func (p *Pets) SomeFunction() (err error){
    p.d = &Dog{} 
    p.c = &Cat{}

    p.d.Name = " Foo "

    p.c.Rename(*p.d)
    return nil
}

func main(){
    p := &Pets{}
    p.SomeFunction()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", p.c.Name)
}
```